# How to create a CSV file on the server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have the following code which works well, but I'd like this to save and write to a CSV file in the folder I'm in. I'm running the JS in node. Big thanks!

```
var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

json = [ { uniq_id: [ 'test' ],
    product_url: [ 'http://www.here.com' ],
    manufacturer: [ 'Disney' ]}]

jsonexport(json,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
    });
```

Note: [jsonexport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport) is a JSON-to-CSV converter.

Comment: Have you made sure your JSON is valid? I see a trailing comma at the end of the last array.

Comment: yea sorry, just a copy paste error to make it simpler looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE you can Use something like this.

```
jsonexport(json,function(err, csv){
   fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.csv", csv, function(err) {
   if(err) {}
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm running this in node so there's no 'window'

Comment: you can Use 
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", csv, function(err) {
    if(err) {}
});
I Updated the Answer